# FORTRAN program produces blank output. Help me

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm writing a code to take an input file and make changes to it line by line(ROWS). I am using some delimiters like '@' and '#' to separate the lines and do different changes to each category of lines. When I run the code, everything is fine but when I execute it, it produces a blank .txt file. Here is my code. Help me.

PROGRAM CONVERSION1

```
    !!DEFINES THE DIFFERENT VARIABLES USED IN CONVERSION1 PROGRAM!!
    INTEGER ::  K, L
    REAL :: A(5)
    CHARACTER :: ROW1

    !!INCLUDES THE BLOCK TO CONTINUE BUILDING ON THE VALUE OF J(LINE NUMBERS)!!
    INCLUDE 'OTHER_CONDITIONS.BLK'


    !!OPENS EXISTING FILE TO BE READ AND THEN PROGRAM WRITES IT TO 2ND MODIFIED FILE!!
    OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE='C:\MSDEV\Projects\UUDF_Conversion\BXK__96B.TXT')
    OPEN(UNIT=2, FILE='C:\MSDEV\Projects\UUDF_Conversion\BXK__96B_MODIFIED.TXT')

    !!TO OBTAIN AN ARRAY OF LINE NUMBERS WHERE A NEW CATEGORY STARTS, SYMBOLIZED BY '@'!!


    L=1
    DO K=1,10000
    READ(1,'(A150)') ROW1
    IF (ROW1(1:1)=='@') THEN
    A(L)= K
    L = L+1
    ENDIF
    ENDDO 
    CONTINUE

    PRINT(*,*) ROW, ROW1

    !!DO LOOP GOES THROUGH EACH AND EVERY LINE OF THE DOCUMENT CHECKING FOR CONDITIONS MET IN ORDER TO MANIPULATE!!
    DO J=1,10000
    READ(1,'(A150)') ROW

            !!AIRPORT DATA!!
            IF ((J==2) .AND. (ROW(73:73).NE. ' ') .AND. (ROW(80:80).EQ.'|')) THEN
                WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:75) // ROW(78:150)
            ELSEIF ((J==5) .AND. (ROW(8:8).NE. ' ') .AND. (ROW(15:15).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:10) // ROW(13:150)
            ELSEIF ((J==6) .AND. (ROW(27:27).NE. ' ') .AND. (ROW(34:34).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:29) // ROW(32:150)
            ELSEIF ((J==7) .AND. (ROW(18:18).NE. ' ') .AND. (ROW(25:25).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:20) // ROW(23:150)

            !!RUNWAY DATA BEFORE THE FIRST '#'!!            
            ELSEIF ((J==(A(1)+1)) .AND. (ROW(17:17).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:12) // ROW(15:150)
            ELSEIF ((J==(A(1)+2)) .AND. (ROW(11:11).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:6) // ROW(9:150)
            ELSEIF ((J==(A(1)+3)) .AND. (ROW(17:17).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:12) // ROW(15:150)
            ELSEIF ((J==(A(1)+4)) .AND. (ROW(25:25).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:20) // ROW(23:150)
            ELSEIF ((J==(A(1)+5)) .AND. (ROW(31:31).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:26) // ROW(29:150)
            ELSEIF ((J.GT.(A(1)+6)) .AND. (ROW(1:1).NE.'@') .OR. (ROW(1:1).NE.'#')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:39) // ROW(42:150)
            ELSEIF ((J.GT.A(1)) .AND. (J.LT.A(2)) .AND. (ROW(1:1)=='#')) THEN
                    CALL RUNWAY_DATA

            !!NAVIGATIONAL AID DATA!!       
            ELSEIF ((J==(A(2)+1)) .AND. (ROW(101:101).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:96) // ROW(99:150)
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:26) // ROW(35:150)
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:71) // ROW(74:150)
            ELSEIF ((J==(A(3)-1)) .AND. (J=='#')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') '@'

            !!OBSTRUCTION 1!!       
            ELSEIF ((J.GT.A(3)) .AND. (ROW(129:129).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:124) // ROW(127:150)

            !!OBSTRUCTION 2!!       
            ELSEIF ((J.GE.A(4)) .AND. (ROW(108:108).EQ.'|')) THEN
                    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:103) // ROW(106:150) 

            !!IF ALL ELSE FAILS!!
            ELSE
                WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW
            ENDIF

    END DO
    CONTINUE                    
    END

    !!SUBROUTINE RUNWAY_DATA TO MANIPULATE DATA AFTER THE '@' IN RUNWAY DATA SECTION AFTER A '#'!!
    SUBROUTINE RUNWAY_DATA

    !!REDEFINES EXISTING VARIABLES FROM MAIN PROGRAM!!

    INCLUDE 'OTHER_CONDITIONS.BLK'


    !!USES THE EXISTING LINE NUMBER FROM MAIN PROGRAM TO PROCEED ON AND CHECK LINE BY LINE FOR CONDITIONS MET WITHIN 2 '#'S'!!
    J=J+1
    IF (ROW(17:17).EQ.'|') THEN
       WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:12) // ROW(15:150)
    ENDIF

    J=J+1
    IF (ROW(11:11).EQ.'|') THEN
        WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:6) // ROW(9:150)
    ENDIF

    J=J+1
    IF (ROW(17:17).EQ.'|') THEN
        WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:12) // ROW(15:150)
    ENDIF

    J=J+1
    IF (ROW(25:25).EQ.'|') THEN
        WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:20) // ROW(23:150)
    ENDIF

    J=J+1
    IF (ROW(31:31).EQ.'|') THEN
        WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:26) // ROW(29:150)
    ENDIF

    J=J+1
    IF ((ROW(1:1).NE.'@') .OR.(ROW(1:1).NE.'#')) THEN             
        WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:39) // ROW(42:150)    
    ENDIF

    J=J+1
    IF ((ROW(1:1).EQ.'#') .OR. (ROW(1:1).EQ.'@')) THEN
    STOP
    ENDIF        

    RETURN
    END SUBROUTINE RUNWAY_DATA
```

Block Program "OTHER_CONDITIONS.BLK"

```
    COMMON /INDEX_POSITION/ J
    INTEGER J


    COMMON /LINE/ ROW
    CHARACTER ROW
```

Comment: I suggest adding debugging output statements to understand which branch is being taken.  Or use a debugger.   Is the output file zero size or does it contain blanks?

Comment: I debugged the output statements and realized that the first part of my program is not even going through. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the declarations or with the first DO loop?

Comment: Do you intend to read the file in both do loops, K and J?   You might have a subscript bounds error with array A.  I suggest compiling with the option to check array bounds.

Comment: Yes I intend on reading the file for both the loops involving the integers K and J. I just debugged it successfully for the array A and realized that I am getting all the positions with '@' in ascending order but I'm getting all 5 times its being updated. What's wrong with the array and reading it twice?

Comment: If you want to read in the same lines a second time, you have to rewind your file to go back to the beginning.

Comment: I don't see the code CLOSEing the file it is writing to.  If your production version of the code omits it, try inserting it.

Comment: What impact do you expect those CONTINUE statements to have ?  I'm sure their presence is irrelevant to your current problem, I have a strong hunch that they are entirely irrelevant and could be deleted without changing the semantics of your program.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Developer Studio in Fortran PowerStation 4.0. I know its old but I'm using F77. How do I rewind the file back?

Comment: I'm able to run the code successfully now because of the rewind. Thanks guys! But the code is still not processing after the J==A(1)+1 portion. I think the program is not able to access array A properly. Is there a problem with the way its being stored, declared or accessed?

Comment: Rewind by using the REWIND statement: REWIND(unit=2), for example.  BTW, it is often dangerous to open files with small unit numbers.  I myself, following the advice of other programmers, never open with a number less than 10.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem with the "DO K" loop?  It looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: I figured it all out successfully. Thanks guys. Now the issue is, how do I automatically cycle the program through a directory to input all the files with specific extensions?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the problem, but depending on the input you could have a subscript error.   I suggest a change such as:

```
implicit none

integer, parmeter :: max_at_cnt
real, dimension (max_at_cnt) :: A
```

...

```
L=1
DO K=1,10000
   READ(1,'(A150)') ROW1
   IF (ROW1(1:1)=='@') THEN
      if ( L <= max_at_cnt) then
         A(L)= K
         L = L+1
      else
         write (*, *) "Too many @s in the file!"
      end if
   END IF
END DO
```